# Is there any implementation of change language available on button click in react native expo localization..?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, expo

I am trying to implement multilanguage support of arabic language in react native expo app. I found many packages on internet but I am using localization module in my expo app. For that I found a solved example on expo snack.
https://snack.expo.io/@marcelkalveram/localizaton-example
but its giving an error. can anybody solve the error.
I want to change the language of whole expo app in arabic on button click, but I haven't found such implementation in expo app.
If any one has encountered similar problem in expo app or if anyone knows another good solution which fulfills my requirement of changing app language on button click, please help..
Thanks..

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please edit your question following the guidelines at https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score -1):

Use `i18n-js` with `expo localization`, read the expo documentation for the usage. https://docs.expo.io/versions/latest/sdk/localization/